# Ajax in plugin settings page returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: ajax, admin-menu

I've read a bunch of questions and copied my code from the codex, but still no luck. I get this error message when I hit my submit button:

[image]

my php functions and JS looks like this:

```
function enqueue_admin_settings_js($hook) {
  global $bblm_settings;

  if ( $hook != $bblm_settings )
    return;

  wp_enqueue_script('admin_settings_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'admin_settings.js', array('jqQ'));

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_admin_settings_js');

function bblm_process_ajax(){
  echo "This is my response";
  var_dump($_POST);
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_bblm_results', 'bblm_process_ajax');
```

The used `jqQ`dependency is me using `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`but I have also tried with the wordpress own `jquery` I still get the same error.
Here is how I register and enqueue the script:

```
function enqueue_my_scripts_jq($hook) {
  global $bblm_settings;
  wp_register_script(
    'jqQ',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
    );

  if ( $hook == $bblm_settings ){
    wp_enqueue_script('jqQ');
    }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_my_scripts_jq');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_my_scripts_jq');
```

and at last here is my JS wich is located in the file `admin_settings.js` enqueued above.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    //alert('ready');
    $('#team-form').submit(function () {
      var data = {
        action: 'bblm_result',
      };
      $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        alert(response);
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
```

Again, I have tried using `jQuery`instead of `$` when using the Wordpress own `jquery`dependency, but it doesn't make a difference.

the PHP Code is inside my main PHP file for my plugin, just saying because I've read an older question where this wasn't the case and the reason for it not working. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

damn it! I just found it... my JS says `action: 'bblm_result'` but my PHP function is looking for `wp_ajax_bblm_results` ... there go my 3hours of searching

Comment: Have you considered using the easier REST API? In this scenario you'd have gotten a message saying the endpoint didn't exist, rather than a cryptic 400 http error code

Comment: This isn't right. If the action in JS was `bblm_results` then the correct hook is in fact `wp_ajax_bblm_results`. Your problem seems to be that you're not setting `ajaxurl`.

Comment: @TomJNowell haven't worked with the WP REST API yet. But I will give it a try.

@JacobPeattie the ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to `admin-ajax.php`. You have misread my JS just like I did. The JS says `bblm_result` without a S at the end. The `add_action`function inside my PHP tho is looking for `wp_ajax_bblm_results` with a S at the end. 
cheers 